# Self referencing entity raise Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Trying to create a class Note which has a self reference because a note can be shared by many notes, with a 1-n relationship. I added foreign key to `SharedNoteID` property and made it `nullable`. Anyway I still get

> "Unable to determine a valid ordering for dependent operations"

when I try to save a Note, even the first one (so with SharedNoteID as null). I'm using Entity-framework 6.1.3 code first. What is wrong?

This is my entity

```
public class Note
{
    public Note()
    {
        SharingNotes = new List<Note>();
    }

    public long ID { get; set; }

    //other properties

    public long? SharedNoteID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SharedNoteID")]
    public Note SharedNote { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Note> SharingNotes { get; set; }
}
```

This is my DBContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Comment: Databases are flat and cannot have a table nested.  What you need to do is to have the table contain a primary key field with unique id.   Then reference the primary key.  The key is usually a number or a string and number.  The number being unique.

Comment: @jdweng can't get you. ID is the primary key and SharedNoteID is the foreign key referencing the ID.

Comment: But how does EF know that `ID` is the primary key? I personally like to have all things in plain sight so I'd start with decorating `ID` with `KeyAttribute` and navigation properties with `InversePropertyAttribute`. Not sure if it's going to help though...

Comment: @Grx70 EF should know because of naming convention. ID or NoteID would be treated as primary key. Anyway tried to add key and InverseProperty attribute but with no luck.

Comment: Fair enough. Are you sure you don't have any circular references or anything of the like? Also, as a side note, is the `SharedNote` property not `virtual` intentionally or by mistake?

Comment: @Grx70 You're right, SharedNote should be virtual. I forgot it, thanks to point it. Anyway the problem persists.

Comment: sorry it was my fault i did not asked you for the EF version nr +1 from me

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was not in EF code but in the Controller (asp.net 5). This was the error:

```
public ViewResult Create(long sharedNote=0)
{
    Note note = new Note();
    note.SharedNoteID = sharedNote;
    return View(note);
}
```

I had to change to

```
public ViewResult Create(long? sharedNote)
{
    Note note = new Note();
    note.SharedNoteID = sharedNote;
    return View(note);
}
```